# The number of transpositions between two permutations

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Suppose it is possible, through many steps, to move from the permutation $\pi$ to the permutation $\sigma$ by multiplying, at each step, by a transposition.

Knowing that they are not necessarily conjugates, I want to find:

1. In how many ways (The maximum number) I can move from $\pi$ to $\sigma$.
2. bound the maximum number of steps needed to switch from $\pi$ to $\sigma$ (is there a reference).

**EDIT 2**
In other words, as [Peter Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5676/peter-taylor) proposed:

Let $d(\pi,\sigma)$ be the length of the smallest sequence of transpositions we need to multiply by the permutation $\pi$ to take it to $\sigma$.

1. How can I bound or even calculate the number of sequences of length $d(\pi,\sigma)$ which take $\pi$ to $\sigma$? (I am looking for any idea)
2. How can I bound or even calculate $d(\pi,\sigma)$ (This one is answered as explained above)?

It is known that the number of transpositions in the symmetric group $S_n$ is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and also it is possible to decompose a certain permutation into disjoint cycles, but I don't how to collect these results to answer my question!

Any kind of help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** I don't think my question is a duplicate! it consists of two parts and the marked question answers only one question! The linked question is not talking about the first part of my question!

Comment: Note that the number of steps to move from $\pi$ to $\sigma$ is equal to the number of transpositions one needs to multiply together to form $\pi\sigma^{-1}$; this is a question whose answer is known.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the link but I don't think it answers my question especially that I am trying to bound the maximum number of possible ways to move between both permutations.

Concerning the distance you talked about it, I found something similar where the distance equals (n - the number of cycles) but I can't find a reference!

Comment: There is no maximum. You can insert $\tau\tau^{-1}\tau\tau^{-1}...\tau\tau^{-1}$ for any transposition $\tau$, with any number of repetitions.

Comment: @LeeMosher so you mean there is no upperbound for the number of ways to move between both permutations by keep multiplying at each step by a transposition! Is this possible?

Comment: To strengthen Lee's point, you have a graph with cycles, so you can just go around a cycle rather than bouncing along an edge. I suspect that what you ought to be asking is "Let $d(\pi, \sigma)$ be the length of the smallest sequence of transpositions which takes $\pi$ to $\sigma$. 1. How can I bound or even calculate $d(\pi, \sigma)$? 2. How can I bound or even calculate the number of sequences of length $d(\pi, \sigma)$ which take $\pi$ to $\sigma$?"

Comment: @PeterTaylor you mixed up between the parts of my question! part 1 of my question is the same as part 2 of yours and part 2 of mine is the same as part 1 of yours! Here *(the number of sequences of length d(π,σ) which take π to σ)* is the same as the number of ways I can go between both permutations

Comment: I did that deliberately, because IMO they make more sense in that order.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ah ok I got it. So in your opinion I can't count the number of sequences?

Comment: No idea, although I know that at a practical level it gets difficult when the transpositions are limited to adjacent transpositions. But $d(\pi, \sigma)$ is almost certainly easier to calculate and $(\textrm{number of transpositions})(\textrm{number of transpositions } - 1)^{d(\pi, \sigma) - 1}$ is a loose upper bound for the number of paths.

Comment: @PeterTaylor could you kindly add your last comment as an answer with little more clarifications? Thanks in advance